# Preserve an arbitrary order in ObservableCollection with DynamicData

Tags: c#, observablecollection, dynamic-data

I have a `Items = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();`

It has elements I am displaying in the UI. It's also manually ordered by a drag-n-drop component that preforms the necesary moves to the `Items`-list.

I also want to filter the `Items`-list by a keyword search and generate a new, filtered list to be displayed. For this, I've tried using [DynamicData](https://github.com/reactivemarbles/DynamicData) like so:

```
var searchFilterObs = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Search)
    .Select([build filter for ViewModels using Search]);
Items
    .ToObservableChangeSet()
    .Filter(searchFilterObs)
    .Bind(out _filteredList)
    .Subsribe();
```

Problem is, DynamicData does not preserve origianl order of items and `ViewModel` object don't have anything in themselves to deduce the order by, since they it's the `Items` list alone that maintains their order.

Is there a good way to maintain or re-establis the original order of the filtered items?
I have tired using a `.Sort()` method that's based on the original list, but it doesn't seem to trigger the sorting when needed.

Comment: Have you tried Items.Select((n, i) => new { Value = n, Index = i }) to work on wrapped objects that include the original position i in the list and sort by i at the end. I agree it is far from ideal but...

Comment: @Dubbs777 Seems this alone won't solve the problem. The major problem here is that the resulting `IEnumerable` is no longer a `ObservableCollection`, which in turn tanks the use of `.ToObservableChangeSet()`. I'll have to see if there's a way derive a new `ObservableCollection` from the original using this or similar function.